# codeigniter Jquery File Upload cannot create thumbnail

Tags: codeigniter, thumbnails, jquery-file-upload

i had following [tutorial](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/jQuery-File-Upload-9.5-with-CodeIgniter-2.1.4) jquery file upload and codeigniter step by step (by Sebastian Tschan). in last line Sebastian say "I had a problem with seeing images/thumbnails initially then I realized I had not set uploads/ directory in my .htacces file".

structure directory :

```
ci-root
  |-uploads (file uploaded here)
  |-.htaccess
  |--thumbs  (file for thumbnail)
```

and my htaccess like this :

```
<Files ~ ".*\..*">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|jpe|gif|png|tif|tiff)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>

<Directory /uploads>
    Options +Indexes
    Satisfy Any
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

it still, i had error :

> Error 500 : The server encountered an internal error and was unable to
>   complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an
>   error in a CGI script.

is there any wrong in my htaccess file? any one can help me? thanks